# Displaying video with URL by adding access token

Tags: ionic-framework, html5-video, access-token, hybrid-mobile-app, office365-restapi

Two scenarios

1) I have the **Access Token (Authorization header)** that need to be sent with every request to **Office 365**. But when we use video tag in Ionic, how can I add this header to the request for video ?
     (I tried appending the URL with **&access_token and &token** - *Didn't work*. )

2) There is an embed code that comes from Office 365, which includes the player and will automatically play the video. 
When I use this and inject the code to a div, the player is showing up with exact time of video displayed. But when I click Play button, black screen appears.

Environment : Using Ionic Framework with cordova-plugin-ms-adal. The output is generated to Android environment. Above scenarios where tested in both emulator and real device.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: i was looking for a configuration that how could we add the request header while requesting URL from video tag. What code should I add ?

Answer (score 0):

The token is used to validate that you have privileges to get the resource. We are not able to  directly use it in an Video HTML5 tag.

And I can reproduce the issue that the embed code of video is blank if it is not login. If you want [Embed a video in another page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/video-rest-operations#embed-a-video-in-another-page) to support the anonymous users play, you can submit the feedback from link [here](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/).